# Range.Resize Clears Range

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to write a function that will fill down a range until it is the same length as another range.

```
Sub fill_down(ByRef drop_range As Range, ByRef same_length As Range)
    drop_range = drop_range.Resize same_length.Rows.Count
    With drop_range
        .FillDown
        Debug.Print .Resize(same_length.Rows.Count).Address
    End With
End Sub

Sub Run()
    Dim wsa As Worksheet
    Dim wsb As Worksheet
    Dim fill As Range
    Dim same_as As Range

    Set wsa = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsb = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    Set fill = wsa.Range("C3")
    Set same_as = wsb.Range("$K$14:$K$33")

    Call fill_down(fill, same_as)
End Sub
```

This results in C3 losing it's formula and the whole range being cleared. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `drop_range = drop_range.Resize same_length.Rows.Count` is incorrect

Comment: Should be `Set drop_range = drop_range.Resize(same_length.Rows.Count)` (in fact it should error the way it's written I think). Or just change the whole function to be `drop_range.Resize(same_length.Rows.Count).FillDown`

Comment: It didn't error which threw me off for a while! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the following work?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Run()
    Dim wsa As Worksheet
    Dim wsb As Worksheet
    Dim fill As Range
    Dim same_as As Range

    Set wsa = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsb = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    Set fill = wsa.Range("C3")
    Set same_as = wsb.Range("$K$14:$K$33")

    fill_down fill, same_as
End Sub

Sub fill_down(ByRef drop_range As Range, ByRef same_length As Range)
    Set drop_range = drop_range.Resize(same_length.Rows.Count, 1)
    With drop_range
        .FillDown
        Debug.Print .Resize(same_length.Rows.Count).Address
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: The second parameter on `Resize` is [optional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Resize), and to keep it in the spirit of OP's question, if it weren't optional it should be `1`.

Comment: @JNevill Why it should be `1`?

Comment: Because they are wanting to select on cell C3 and copy down that cell for whatever length of the range is in their `same_length` range. There is no mention of column counts changing. I mean.. it's a nice feature that it would fill down for multiple columns, but I don't think it's OP's intent. Perhaps I'm reading too much into it.